# OpenXML Changing Default Track Changes Settings

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-powertools

I'm working with OpenXML, specifically tracking changes with a word document. I'd like to change the color of an insertion; however, I can't figure out how to access the insertion color settings using OpenXML or OpenXMLPowerTools. Normally, within an actual word document, you can navigate to markup options in the review tab and set the color of insertions (or deletions). Any ideas on how to do this with OpenXML? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you able share any code?

Comment: I've tried to remove styling defaults using:

wDoc.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.Styles.DocDefaults.RemoveAllChildren();

But didn't do anything. I've tried:
 
        // RevisionView revView = new RevisionView();
            // revView.Markup = new OnOffValue(false);    
            // wDoc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.RemoveAllChildren<RevisionView>();
            // wDoc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.AppendChild(revView);

But this essentially hides all the markup, all I want to do is change the color of an insertion

Comment: I've been working through the OpenXML documentation but there just doesn't seem to be a direct tool for editing the revision markup settings. Maybe I need to directly edit the word xml file?